# Pressing back button on phone has different behaviour to back intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

My app is tabbed, when I start a new activity over the top of the tabs, and press the back button on the phone to return, it returns to the tab I was previously on. When I go back with this intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(EditViewerActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

It doesn't return to the tab I was on before. Is there anyway to get the same behaviour as the back button on the phone in an intent?

Comment: Why don't you use fifnish() at your activity to return back? Why do you want to use Intent?

Comment: what you want to do is use finish() to close the activity, what you are doing now is re-open the first activity.

Comment: Create a finally block and call finish in each of the tabactivities.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to use `finish();`.

Answer (score 0):

finish(); will end the current activity, the proper way would be to use `NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, new Intent(this, MyActivity.class));` which can be used after importing `import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;`
They will both basically do the same thing in the end.